# How to set general formula for each cell on a column in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am wondering if it is possible to set a formula for every cell in a column to sum the cells on the left of, and above itself. I am trying to cumulatively sum up the total time for each activity (row), so that the bottom cell of the column contains the total time.

[image: after I add a row it disrupts the column]

I have tried dragging the selection of some cells to extend the series, which works perfectly, however if I happen to forget an activity and have to insert a new row, all of the cells on that new row are empty and I have to manually sum that time to the total time.

Basically, I am wondering if it is possible to add a general rule to the entire column that sums the cell to the left of, and above itself so that no matter how I manipulate the rows (be it inserting a new row), the total time at the bottom of the column will always be the actual total time.

Comment: I may misunderstand you, but can you not simply do something like `=A2+B1`?

Comment: yep so i did that for those cells, but notice how when i insert a new row, those two cells are empty and don't have those calculations automatically put in. I want each cell in the column to always sum up the cell above and to the left of it, so i dont have to manually add calculations whenever i add a new row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually to get the total of Time using the left cell time value, needs Running Sum. The tricky part is how to avoid the Blank Cell in between.

**So, on the basis of the screen shot I've solved the issue.**

[image]

Write this formula in cell B2 and drag it down.

```
=IF(A2<>"",SUM($A$2:A2),"")
```

Comment: Thank you very much, may I ask what process in Excel this is as I would like to learn more about this

Comment: Nice to hear from you @thomas152374,, basically it's running sum. Place the cell pointer in the B2 and check the Formula bar and notice the Cell address, then use down arrow to move one cell below and again notice the change in Cell address, you find the simple mechanism. keep asking.